# python split string every x characters but except space

Tags: python, string

here is my code

```
    string = '얼굴도 잘 생긴데다 학력에 집안에~ 뭐 뒤쳐지는게 없잖아. 조건이 워낙 좋아야말이지'
    n = 10
    split_string = [string[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(string), n)]
```

and this is the result I want. what should I do?

```
split_string = ['얼굴도 잘 생긴데다 학력', '에 집안에~ 뭐 뒤쳐지는', '게 없잖아. 조건이 워낙', 
                     ' 좋아야말이지']
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to implement your described problem and made assumptions where I was not fully sure about the expected behavior of the program. I assumed that you want to split the string into substrings such that each substring contains at least 10 non-space characters excluding trailing spaces. The concatenation of the susbtrings yields the initial input. Note that a width of 0 yields an endless loop and an empty input yields an empty substring (given that width > 0).

For the snippet below, I have replaced your input (`string`) and substring length (`n`) with a simpler example. Using your instead instead yields your expected result.

```py
string = 'aaa b b b cc  c ee'
width = 3
split_string = []
_from = 0
_to = 0

while True:
    # we have reached the end of the string
    if len(string) +1 == _to:
        split_string += [string[_from:_to]]
        break
    # the substring contains a sufficient number of non-space characters
    if len(string[_from:_to].replace(" ", "")) == width:
        split_string += [string[_from:_to]]
        _from = _to
        continue
    # increase the length of the substring
    _to += 1

print(split_string)
# OUTPUT
# ['aaa', ' b b b', ' cc  c', ' ee']
```

Answer (score 0):

use a for loop for the list and use something like `split_string[i] = split_string[i].replace(" ", "")`

Comment: I think this will not work, because OP requires the space to be present in the output list.

Comment: anything better would be appreciated

i'll also get to learn something new